# Rx skip until a number of seconds have passed

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I have a PublishSubject that keeps emiting a signal every X seconds, I would like to only consider the first item that is emitted after Y seconds.

Example

- observable A emits a "tick" every second
- observable B should only emit this "tick" every 5 seconds, ignoring
  the ones in-between.

That is, skip every item until a certain timespan has passed.

This is **not** a debounce, cause debounce needs the original Observable to stay 5 seconds **without** emitting, but mine is emitting every second.

Comment: Could you draw a marbles diagram?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please have a look at my solution. 'tickEverySecond' will emit a value every second. 'result' will collect all items emitted by 'tickEverySecond' during a time-window of 5 seconds. Every 5 second window the last emitted value from 'tickEverySecond' will be pushed to subscriber.

```
@Test
  public void name() {
    TestScheduler testScheduler = new TestScheduler();
    Flowable<Long> tickEverySecond = Flowable.interval(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, testScheduler);

    Flowable<Long> result = tickEverySecond.window(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, testScheduler).flatMap(longFlowable -> longFlowable.takeLast(1));

    TestSubscriber<Long> test = result.test();

    testScheduler.advanceTimeTo(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    test.assertValueCount(0).assertNotComplete();

    testScheduler.advanceTimeTo(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    test.assertValue(4L).assertNotComplete();

    testScheduler.advanceTimeTo(9, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    test.assertValues(4L).assertNotComplete();

    testScheduler.advanceTimeTo(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    test.assertValues(4L, 9L).assertNotComplete();

    testScheduler.advanceTimeTo(14_999, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    test.assertValues(4L, 9L).assertNotComplete();
  }
```

You can have the same effect with following operator:

```
Flowable<Long> result = tickEverySecond.throttleLast(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, testScheduler);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think *.window()* operator is what you need -
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxSwift/Observables/Window.swift

It partitions events by timeframe, see RxJava documentation -
http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#window-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-